# Get log of mail sent with mail() from PHP (sendmail?)

Tags: linux, php, email, sendmail, exim

After some server changes our PHP configuration got nuked, which caused a client's large mailing list to time out partially through about 4,000 addresses or more. We want to avoid sending a duplicate mail as much as possible, and we have the original mailing list.

The mail was sent using PHP's `mail()` function, which uses `sendmail`, which says it's using `Exim`. I've seen the command:

```
sendmail -bp
```

Which gives me a list of mail that appears was sent. This list isn't very big, and could be accurate (meaning the script timed out after sending only a hundred or so e-mails)

Is `sendmail -bp` the best way to get this listing?

**EDIT:** I can't find any `mail.log` file in `/var/log/mail.log` or via `locate mail.log`, but WHM seems to have some information on this.

Comment: What about /var/log/maillog ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Debian-based systems exim logs data in `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`.

You might find the [eximstats](http://linux.die.net/man/8/eximstats) tool useful for parsing and culling useful information out of that log file.

Comment: In centos, and probably RHEL/fedora, it's in /var/log/exim_mainlog

Answer (score 7):

`sendmail -bp` (and `mailq`) only lists the mail queue: messages queued but not yet sent. It will not include those messages which were delivered successfully.

You should check `/var/log/mail.log` (and other logfiles) - they almost always have records of every transfer.

Answer (score 6):

php 5.3.0 added 2 settings that makes tracking down rogue scripts easy:

```
mail.add_x_header
mail.log
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php